# VUE - Using data () values in createElement method

Tags: html, vue.js, recursion, syntax, iteration

I'm trying to render a few divs in Vuejs as follows:

```
render (createElement) {
    return createElement('div', { class: 'header' },
      Array.apply(null, { length: this.testArray.length }).map(function (i) {
        return createElement('div', { class: 'frame' }, this.testArray)
      })
    )
  }
```

Everything working OK except for the last this.testArray call. Vue detects this.testArray.length but alerts that 'Element is not exported' for variable call within return statement.

Data is stored as follows:

```
data () {
    return {
      testArray: [// my array //]
    }
  }
```

Any orientation about how to use array in return statement will be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t know about createElement method, but I would use arrow function in your example just to be sure that ```this``` in ```this.testArray``` refers to Vue component.

Comment: @PawelKam could you give me an example of that?

Comment: I didn't test, but I had in mind something like this: ```Array.apply(as in your example).map(i => {as in your example})```. See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions The important thig is that arrow functions do not have its own bindings to ```this```, which is useful in Vue.

Comment: @PawelKam thanks to your suggestion, I was able to reference my variable when I added  the arrow syntax to the function. Now I need to figure out how to run through the array. Thank you very much.